# transform data collection into laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I am starting to work with laravel and to obtain my data I use eloquent, so I have a collection of data that looks more or less like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Expense",
    "name": "list",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "Expense",
    "name": "register",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "title": "Expense",
    "name": "show",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "title": "Expense",
    "name": "update",
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Expense",
    "name": "remove",
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "title": "Income",
    "name": "list",
    "id": 7
  },
  {
    "title": "Income",
    "name": "register",
    "id": 8
  },
  {
    "title": "Income",
    "name": "show",
    "id": 9
  },
  {
    "title": "Income",
    "name": "update",
    "id": 10
  },
  {
    "title": "Income",
    "name": "remove",
    "id": 11
  }
]
```

So I was wondering how I could transform this collection with the methods provided by it, or do I need to work with native arrays so that the collection I showed earlier can be as follows:

```
[  
   {  
      "title":"Expense",
      "permissions":[  
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"list"
         },
         {  
            "id":3,
            "name":"show"
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "name":"register"
         },
         {  
            "id":5,
            "name":"update"
         },
         {  
            "id":6,
            "name":"remove"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "title":"Income",
      "permissions":[  
         {  
            "id":7,
            "name":"list"
         },
         {  
            "id":8,
            "name":"show"
         },
         {  
            "id":9,
            "name":"register"
         },
         {  
            "id":10,
            "name":"update"
         },
         {  
            "id":11,
            "name":"remove"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a PHP issue rather than a Laravel one. Eloquent won't change it for you, unless the permissions are linked to another table and then you will get them in that format, what you need to do is simply edit your array natively.

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupBy in laravel collection 
like this

```
$collection = new Collection([
  {
    "title": "Expense",
    "name": "list",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "Expense",
    "name": "register",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "title": "Expense",
    "name": "show",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "title": "Expense",
    "name": "update",
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Expense",
    "name": "remove",
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "title": "Income",
    "name": "list",
    "id": 7
  },
  {
    "title": "Income",
    "name": "register",
    "id": 8
  },
  {
    "title": "Income",
    "name": "show",
    "id": 9
  },
  {
    "title": "Income",
    "name": "update",
    "id": 10
  },
  {
    "title": "Income",
    "name": "remove",
    "id": 11
  }
]);

$grouped = $collection->groupBy('title');

$grouped->toArray();
```